# alternative to jpGraph

Tags: php, jpgraph

This is my first time generating graphs using php. Do you know of any alternatives to jpGraph?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Listed in no particular order, here's a few charting libraries for PHP

[ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com/cdphp.html)

[GraPHPite](http://graphpite.sourceforge.net/)

[LibChart](http://naku.dohcrew.com/libchart/pages/introduction/)

[pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/)

[TeeChart](http://www.steema.com/products/teechart/overview.html)

Answer (score 2):

you have fusion charts , very famous and easy to work

http://www.fusioncharts.com/

with the free edition

http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/